# Google Drive Embed

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-drive-api, mobile-website

My friend and I were asked to make a school Elections Website. We planned on using Google Drive and since our school has G Suite we can make it so that only members with school emails can view the file. This is where the problem starts, iPads cannot open the private Google Drive video embed up even if they are using Chrome and are logged in on their school accounts. Is there any solution to this problem apart from making the videos unlisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When you host a video or any other file on you Drive, you can configure the access permissions.

For this, you hgave to rightclick on the file and select `Share`.

- You can either manually add people with whom you want to share the file (can be also a [Google group](https://groups.google.com/my-groups) which contains all members with whom you want to share):

[image]

- Or, you can activate Link access and set it to "Anyone in your domain can view"

[image]

The latter is the most appropiate if the file is located on a Drive of your school domain - in this case by enabling this option you provide access to your whole school (domain).

- Since your question is tagged with the tag `google-drive-api`:

To perform the sharing request with the API - use the method [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)